# Hyperledger Fabric v0.6, how to add more peer on the network without vagrant and docker?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have installed Fabric v0.6 on my VM ubuntu 16.04 and it works fine for peer, membersrvc, API, chaincode. I'm doing everything the same with this VM as with another VM on the same server. Let's call them *VM1* and  *VM2*. I don't use vagrant or docker.

My project is connecting 4 peers together. I got some advice from different users. Some said that without using vagrant or pulling the image from docker, it will not work. Some said that it works, but my project does not with any VR environment. It's real implementation.

They said that I need to modify some lines in **Core.Yaml** and **membersrvc.yaml** to let the peers discover each other and send acknowledgment message. Some said that I have to do the above step and  port mapping in different servers to make it work.

When I try to edit both files, Sometime I don't understand about it at all. And some tips has no operation and step.

Thx for helping us to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric has come a long way since the v0.6 release. If you are still working with v0.6 it is highly recommended that you upgrade to the most [current release](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). There are a number of on-going efforts to develop supported approaches to deploying Hyperledger Fabric to multiple nodes, and for v1.0 and beyond, our deployments are all Docker based and can support kubernetes and swarm.